# C# Serialize Dictionary<ulong,ulong> to JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dictionary

I am trying to serialize a Dictionary to JSON, and get the following exception:

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(mydict)`
```

> Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.UInt64, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Nullable`1[[System.UInt64, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.

Is there an easy way to do this? Maybe converting the ulongs to strings via LINQ or something relatively terse?

Comment: This is such an awful error message, isn't a value object still an object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Comment: I clearly posted the question first. Why isn't the other one marked as a duplicate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var dict = mapping.ToDictionary(item => item.Key.ToString(), item => item.Value.ToString());`
```

that will convert any `Dictionary<K,V>` to `Dictionary<string,string>` and serialization then works.

Comment: This works perfectly. Worthwhile to note that something like a Dictionary<int, MyClass> can also be serialized in this way while preserving the complex type: mapping.ToDictionary(item => item.Key.ToString(), item => item.Value);

Answer (score 3):

use `NewtonSoft.Json` instead of `JavaScriptSerializer` to overcome this problem:

**Ex:**

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mydict);
```

Answer (score 1):

The blog http://dukelupus.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/asp-net-mvc-json-and-a-generic-dictionary/ describes an extension method 
Dictionary ToJsonDictionary(this Dictionary input)

Comment: While this answer is several years old [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.