# How to pass name value pair to Oracle from .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

I need to pass name value pairs containing column name and column values of table to Oracle from c#.net. How can I do this?, I did take a look at this http://my-tech-talk.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-pass-arrays-from-net-c-to-oracle.html not sure whether I can use this for two dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON as a mediator between C# and Oracle.

For your name/value pairs you can use a Dictionary.

Take a look at [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pljson/files/) for PL/SQL and JSON and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/c-sharp-dictionary-to-json) for C# dictionaries and JSON.

Comment: Length of varchar2 is limited to 4/32K in plsql, so this is not scalable solution for my problem.