# Best way to write javascript to ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

My scenerio is a user could click on 12 different items on the page and depending on which item they click, a div will be populated with text. I was thinking a good way to do this is just pass all the different text strings to the client on their first request rather than doing a possible of 12 different AJAX calls. I figured front loading the client with the initial load time would be better since the text strings aren't long anyways.

What I am trying to figure out is the best way to write a javascript dictionary/hastable in my C# code behind and pass it to the page on load. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Show *your way* so that we can suggest *best way*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can create 12 hidden divs, populate them with HTML and show the appropriate one depending on what the user clicked.
- You can convert the Dictionary object to a JavaScript object literal, something like:

```
var pageContent = {
    button1: "some content",
    button2: "some other content"
    // ...
};
```

Have a look at [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.aspx) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/c-sharp-dictionary-to-json) for code. You can then populate a div with the content depending on button clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void btnHey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 sb.Append("<script language='javascript'>alert('HEY');</script>");

 // if the script is not already registered

 if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Page.GetType(), "HeyPopup"))

      ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "HeyPopup", sb.ToString());
}
```

You can take a look at this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/185586-aspnet-calling-javascript-from-code-behind/ I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of the client you've basically got two choices:

1. Trigger an AJAX call on page load to get the data asynchronously. (See Sjoerd's answer)
2. Get ASP to push the data directly into your HTML / JavaScript. (See Ewerton / Scorpio's answers)

If you're uncomfortable having ASP generate your JS dynamically you could also get it to output a script tag with your data in it:

```
<script type="text/json" id="strings">
     <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="JavascriptData" />
</script>
```

Produces:

```
 <script type="text/json" id="strings">
     { "div1" : "First String",
       "div2" : "Second String",
       "etc" : "And so on" }
 </script>
```

And then read the data in your javascript:

```
var json = document.getElementById('strings').InnerHTML;
var strings = JSON.Parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript will do the trick

Comment: Yeah I was looking at doing that, it just seemed like their could be a better way. Such as a method to just write a dictionary out to the source rather than building up a javascript string.

Comment: Look at ScrptManager.RegisterArray(), that will simply create variables

Answer (score 0):

To solve such a problem myself, I have made a HttpHandler that returns JSON:

```
public class JsonData : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(GetData());
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(json);
    }
}
```

In the Javascript of my ASPX I use jQuery to retrieve the data:

```
$.getJSON("/JsonData.ashx", null, function (data) { ... });
```

This is really an out-of-band solution, in that the ASPX file retrieves a second file with the data.

What I also sometimes see is something like this:

```
<script>
    var myData = '<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="JavascriptData" />';
</script>
```

Where JavascriptData is then filled in the codebehind. I don't really like this method, but it is simple and it works. Don't forget to escape your quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your html content in a string format in hidden fields, or you can populate 12 separate divs from your server side code. Then write some javascript to show-hide divs based on the button clicks.