# Convert dictionary object to string to output as json

Tags: c#, json

I am using razor in webmatrix.
I have a dictionary object

```
var occupancyTotalDic = new Dictionary<double, int>();
```

Once I have filled the dictionary with data I wish to output as JSON as a response to populate a flot chart

```
Dictionary<String, String> input = new Dictionary<String, String>();
occupancyTotalDic = input.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => (String)item.Value);

Response.ContentType = "application/json";
Response.Write(Json.Encode(occupancyTotalDic));
```

How do I convert my dictionary to contain strings so that I can output as JSON?

Comment: You show code here. Does it work? Do you get any error messages, at compile-time or run-time?

Comment: Is it ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: Did you google how to use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json)?

Answer (score 0):

Since Webmatrix can't compile MVC application I assume you are using ASP.NET webforms.

Tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/5597628/713789

If you are using MVC then just use `JsonResult test(){ return Json(myobj);}`