# C# - JSON Serialization of Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am new in C# development,

In my project, I try to save a `Dictionary` instance by serializing it into a `Settings` storage with this code:

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> GetKeys()
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> keys = null;
    try {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        keys = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>>>(Settings.Default.keys);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Print(e.Message);
    }
    return keys;
}

private static void SetKeys(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, string>> keys)
{
    try
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Settings.Default.keys = ser.Serialize(keys);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Print(e.Message);
    }
}
```

My problems occurs when I try to invoke `SetKeys` method. A `ThreadAbortException` is thrown:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>       Evaluation requires a thread to run temporarily. Use the Watch window to perform the evaluation.

Have you got an idea how can I resolve my error?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13754871/1099945

Comment: Serializing/deserializing dictionaries is always a problem source.  I'd suggest ditching the dictionary and create your own configuration collection extending https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx as this is a keyed collection that is also a Collection<T>, which is easily serialized/deserialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), but if you want to use `JavaScriptSerializer`:

Try:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(keys.ToDictionary(item => item.Key.ToString(), item => item.Value.ToString()));
```

Or:

```
string jsonString = serializer.Serialize((object)keys);
```