# Webservice error in kentico CMS after upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I have created a web service using Kentico CMS 8.0 I've upgraded the instance to 8.2. When I try to call methods from my web service I get error in [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYQTL.jpg).

This is my method:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string ProcessOrderGeneralDonation(Dictionary<string, object> request)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> response;

    ProcessDonationOrder(request, out response);

    return JSONResponse(true, "Data Populated", response);
}
private void ProcessDonationOrder(Dictionary<string, object> request, out Dictionary<string, object> response, bool isChampionOfCare = false)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { };

    #region Customer
    var customer = GetNewCustomerInfo(request);

    var customerType = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(request["customer_type"], 0);

    if (customerType == 2) //company
    {
        customer.CustomerCompany = ValidationHelper.GetString(request["customer_organization"], String.Empty);
    }

    CustomerInfoProvider.SetCustomerInfo(customer);

    var country = CountryInfoProvider.GetCountryInfo(ValidationHelper.GetString(request["customer_country"], String.Empty).Replace(" ", ""));

    //var state = StateInfoProvider.GetStateInfo(ValidationHelper.GetString(request["customer_province"], String.Empty));

    // Create new address object
    var customerAddress = GetNewCustomerAddressInfo(request, customer);

    if (country != null)
        customerAddress.AddressCountryID = country.CountryID;

    // Create the address
    AddressInfoProvider.SetAddressInfo(customerAddress);

    customerAddress.SetValue("AddressPhone", ValidationHelper.GetString(request["customer_phone"], String.Empty));
    customerAddress.SetValue("AddressStateOthers", ValidationHelper.GetString(request["customer_province"], String.Empty));
    customerAddress.Update();

    // Create order addresses from customer address
    OrderAddressInfo orderBillingAddress = OrderAddressInfoProvider.CreateOrderAddressInfo(customerAddress);
    OrderAddressInfo orderShippingAddress = OrderAddressInfoProvider.CreateOrderAddressInfo(customerAddress);

    // Set the order addresses
    OrderAddressInfoProvider.SetAddressInfo(orderBillingAddress);
    OrderAddressInfoProvider.SetAddressInfo(orderShippingAddress);
    #endregion

    var guid = ValidationHelper.GetGuid(request["guid"], Guid.Empty);

    string message;

    #region Shopping Cart
    //Get Product
    var product = GetProductSKUInfo(guid, out message);

    if (product == null)
    {
        response = null;
        return;
    }

    //Get Shopping Cart
    var cart = GetShoppingCart();

    // Add item to cart object
    var param = new ShoppingCartItemParameters(product.SKUID, 1)
    {
        ProductOptions = new List<ShoppingCartItemParameters>
        {
            new ShoppingCartItemParameters(ValidationHelper.GetInteger(request["designation_id"], 0), 1),
            new ShoppingCartItemParameters(ValidationHelper.GetInteger(request["donation_amount_id"], 0), 1)
        }
    };

    if (isChampionOfCare)
    {
        //Get Champions Of Care Option Id 
        var options = OptionCategoryInfoProvider.GetProductOptionCategories(product.SKUID, true, OptionCategoryTypeEnum.Text);

        var opt = options.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault(x => x["CategoryName"].ToString().ToLower() == "coc");
        if (opt != null)
        {
            var categoryId = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(opt["CategoryID"], 0);
            var skuOpt = GetSKUOptions(product.SKUID, categoryId) as DataTable;

            if (skuOpt != null)
            {
                var cocId = ValidationHelper.GetInteger(skuOpt.Rows[0]["SKUID"], 0);
                var cocParam = new ShoppingCartItemParameters(cocId, 1)
                {
                    Text = ValidationHelper.GetString(request["coc_text"], string.Empty)
                };

                param.ProductOptions.Add(cocParam);
            }
        }
    }

    ShoppingCartItemInfo cartItem = cart.SetShoppingCartItem(param);

    cartItem.CartItemCustomData["other_amount"] = ValidationHelper.GetDouble(request["donation_other_amount"], 0);

    cart.ShoppingCartCustomData["donation_type"] = "GEN";

    // Save item to database
    ShoppingCartItemInfoProvider.SetShoppingCartItemInfo(cartItem);

    cart.ShoppingCartBillingAddress = orderBillingAddress;

    cart.ShoppingCartShippingAddress = orderShippingAddress;

    cart.Customer = customer;

    cart.Update();

    ShoppingCartInfoProvider.SetOrder(cart);

    dictionary.Add("order_id", cart.OrderId);

    UpdateDonor(request, cart.OrderId);

    if (EnablePurchase)
    {
        Receipt responseReceipt;

        request.Add("product_sku", product.SKUID);

        Purchase(request, cart, customer, customerAddress, out responseReceipt);

        var paymentSuccessed = !responseReceipt.GetMessage().Contains("DECLINED");

        if (paymentSuccessed)
        {
            //HandleOrderNotification(cart);
            SendInvoiceEmail(cart.OrderId);
        }

        dictionary.Add("moneris_message", responseReceipt.GetMessage());
    }

    #endregion

    response = dictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that `JSONResponse()` doesn't know how to serialize a `Dictionary<string,object>` to a valid JSON format.

Take a look at some of these answers to help you solve this problem.  Most of them suggest using a JSON library like [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620173/2344773

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5597628/2344773

Answer (score 0):

i have already added JSON.NET to my project and JSONResponse() function

```
private string JSONResponse(bool success, string message, object data = null)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "success", success }, { "message", message }, { "data", data } };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
}
```