# Convert Dictionary to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, json

first time asking questions here.

I currently have a Dictionary in C# that I want to serialize into JSON using:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDict);
```

Works A1, getting results

> {"Key1":["Item1","Item2","Item3"],"Key2":["Item1","Item2","Item3"]}

However, I would like to get my JSON response in this format to be usable with Jquery addons:

> {"ID":"Key1",   "Value": ["Val":"Item1","Val:":"Item2","Val":"Item3"]
>   }, {  "ID":"Key2", 
>   "Value":["Val":"Item1","Val:":"Item2","Val":"Item3"] }

Without having to loop through the dictionary and rebuild it manually. Is there any decent ways to do it?

Thank you

Comment: The JSON format you're trying to achieve is invalid; you can't have an associative array as in your `Value` property and the objects would need to be in an array. Syntax issues aside, you would probably be best to create your own class with `ID` and `Value` properties and then add that to a `List<>` before serialising it to JSON

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Comment: Seconding what @RoryMcCrossan said, if you upload your desired JSON to http://jsonlint.com/ you will get parse errors such as `Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'`.  Json.NET isn't going to be able to directly generate a string in that format.