# C# Dictionary to Json Format

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

This Question is related to Json data format. I have a dictionary with Key value pair. 
ConfigA 1200
ConfigB 1500
ConfigC 800
ConfigD 2
.I need to convert the all dictionary values to 1 json format
[{"ConfigA":"1200","ConfigB":"1500","ConfigC":"800","ConfigD":"2"}]
Could anyone help me how to do it ?

Comment: use newtonsoft.   http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add System.Web.Extensions.dll and try the below code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int> {
            {"ConfigA", 1200},
            {"ConfigB", 1500},
            {"ConfigC", 800},
            {"ConfigD", 2}
        };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Console.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(dictionary));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Just out of interest, do you know that you are creating an array containing a single object with 4 parameters? Assuming JavaScript will be the target of this structure then you will be referencing data[0].config*. You may want to leave off the square brackets at start and end to make the recipient JS code easier to understand. Example of before and after below.

```
// using array
var data = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"ConfigA":"1200","ConfigB":"1500","ConfigC":"800","ConfigD":"2"}]')

var A = data[0].configA
alert('Value of A=' + A)  // Will show 1200

var B = data[0].configB
alert('Value of B=' + B)  // Will show 1500

// without array
var dataV2 = jQuery.parseJSON('{"ConfigA":"1200","ConfigB":"1500","ConfigC":"800","ConfigD":"2"}')

var A2 = data.configA
alert('Value of A2=' + A2)  // Will show 1200

var B2 = data.configB
alert('Value of B2=' + B2)  // Will show 1500
```