# Convert dictionary object into Json string

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, collections

I have a dictionary object which is declared as shown below.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<DataRow>>> lineList = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, List<DataRow>>>();
```

I want to convert this object into Json string but when I used following code, It only considered first object from dictionary list and then added rest of the data in it regardless of for which key it is connected.

```
var linechartString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lineList);
```

I would like to know if there is a different function available which can convert my dictionary object into JSON string.

Comment: Can you please add line of code where you serializing?

Comment: @kat1330 I edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

This sample serializes a dictionary to JSON

```
Dictionary<string, int> points = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "Ali", 1111},
    { "Hasan", 2222},
    { "HoseynJan", 3333 }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(points, Formatting.Indented);

Console.WriteLine(json);
// {
//   "Ali": 1111,
//   "Hasan": 2222,
//   "HoseynJan": 3333
// }
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at this link

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializedictionary.htm

The second way

Dictionary>**>

**Dictionary>** you can try to Serialize firsly For each Main Dictionary element. After this, Serialize Main Dictionary ;) I hope this will hep