# how to send dictionary json key value pairs from C# Socket Client to python socket server

Tags: python, c#, .net, sockets, client-server

I am trying to send data to Python via C# client. My code works for sending a string  from c# client to python server . But how to send dictionary key value pairs from and c# client to python server .

For reference i am using the below code
This is my c# client

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

// State object for receiving data from remote device.  
public class StateObject
{
    // Client socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    // The port number for the remote device.  
    private const int port = 11000;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.  
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.  
    private static String response = String.Empty;

    private static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.  
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.  
            // The name of the    
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[2];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.  
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.  
            Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.  
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.  
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);

            // Release the socket.  
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.  
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.  
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.  
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.  
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket   
            // from the asynchronous state object.  
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.  
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.  
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.  
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.  
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.  
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        StartClient();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

AND below is my python server which receives the string . But how to send dictionary key value from C# client to python socket server

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
host=socket.gethostname()
port=7634
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
connection, client_address = s.accept()
while True:
  frames= connection.recv(6000)
  data_receive=frames.decode()
  print(data_receive)
```

How to modify the C# code for sending a key value pairs and how to fetch that in python
foreg {"company":"abc","id":1}
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual issue you're facing in doing this?

Comment: Just transphorm your dictionary into a json string https://stackoverflow.com/a/25797924/14900199 , and send it using the `Send(Socket client, String data)` method.

Comment: @Self how did you know the server eats Json? None of this code seems to be Json anything, and the only mention of something that looks like it is an explanation of example keyvalue pairs to send..