# How can I flatten my data model's JSON output in C#?

Tags: c#

If I have a model like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Address { get; set; }
}
```

Where the dictionary could have data like

```
"Number", "18"
"Line1", "Knotta Street"
"Line2", "Thrumpton-on-Thames"
"Postcode", "SW1 2AA"
```

Is there any way I can flatten an instance of this model to create a new, temporary anonymous object that'd look like this:

```
Name : Jim
DOB : 21/01/1990
Number : 18
Line1 : Knotta Street
Line2 : Thrumpton-on-Thames
Postcode : SW1 2AA
```

With the ultimate goal being that I can output it to JSON in that completely flat 1:1 format

Comment: A dictionary with that data would *already* produce the desired JSON when serialized.  There's no need to construct a new object to accomplish that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c)

Comment: I would create a custom converter for the Dictionary, how you would do that depends on how you are serializing your json.

Comment: @Servy not quite; if you serialize `Person` you'll get structured JSON, not flattened JSON. The author needs to manually add the key value pairs of existing properties along with the key value pairs of the `Address` dictionary, to a unified dictionary that represents the model in a flat format, then serialize just that unified dictionary. I have to do something similar due to a data provider I work with.

Comment: @Tacoタコス I don't think the OP is unfamiliar with how to add two keys to a dictionary.  They got the one that they have to have what it needs, so I don't see any reason they wouldn't be able to add any others they need it to have.  The question states that they want to construct an anonymous object to make this JSON (which they don't need).  They just need to know to serialize a dictionary to produce that JSON.

Comment: @Servy fair point, I misunderstood your first comment then :)

Comment: @ScottHunter I had asked the same question earlier with all of my attempts and it was so verbose and confusing that I ended up with answers that didn't actually answer the question at all. This was my 2nd and more fruitful shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a flattened dictionary. You can achieve this by manually adding your keys and values for static properties, and then dynamically adding your existing key value pairs in the `Address` dictionary.

Personally, I recommend creating a method that flattens out the data and gives it back as a JSON string:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Address { get; set; }
    public string GetFlattenedJson() {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object> {
            { "Name", Name },
            { "DOB", DOB }
        };
        foreach (var datum in Address)
            result.Add(datum.Key, datum.Value);

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    }
}
```

Then, when you need the flattened data, you simply access it with that method:

```
var flatJson = myPerson.GetFlattenedJson();
```

Comment: Thanks - I had been wondering if there was a linq select to create an anonymous object which might avoid me having to write a `foreach` even though it'd be looping behind the scenes anyway, but this is very neat and will get the job done.

Comment: @jamheadart no problem; honestly, there's a way to do it with Linq, but this version is easier to understand and follow. :)

Answer (score -1):

Clarifying Edit: dynamic objects aren't anonymous objects, I demonstrated with dynamic since it's the closest solution available - a real anonymous object can't have properties populated at runtime based on a dictionary (unless code generation on the fly is introduced), only dynamic objects support that.

---

You need to use dynamic to generate an anonymous object with dynamic properties, usually `ExpandoObject` is used in such scenarios:

```
        var person = new Person
        {
            Name = "Jim",
            DOB = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Address = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Number", "18" },
                { "Line1", "Knotta Street" },
                { "Line2", "Thrumpton-on-Thames" },
                { "Postcode", "SW1 2AA" },
            }
        };
        dynamic flatterned = new ExpandoObject();
        flatterned.Name = person.Name;
        flatterned.DOB = person.DOB;

        foreach (var kv in person.Address)
        {
            (flatterned as IDictionary<string, object>).Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(flatterned));
```

Note that as others have commented, there's no need to create an object then serialized to JSON, but that's what you asked for so I figured it could help showing you.

Comment: That's not an anonymous object.  It's an `ExpandoObject`.  It has a name.  You named it.  And anonymous object is a specific thing and this is not that.  So in addition to being a really bad solution to the problem, it's *also* not what the OP asked for.  So it's both technically incorrect and also not a useful solution to this problem.

Comment: I know what an anonymous object is, only there's no way to create an anonymous object with custom properties based on a dictionary without code generation on the fly, so I provided the closest thing which is a dynamic object. No need to be harsh for a solution close to the author's intent.

Comment: If you know what an anonymous object is, and you know that this isn't creating one, then *why did you claim this was creating an anonymous object when you know it's not*.  It's not a good solution to the problem, and it's not what the question asked for.  The only thing you've done is produce a much less efficient dictionary, which you're proposing the OP use instead of the *more* efficient dictionary they're already using.  That's not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ExpandoObjects` to easily achieve what you are looking for. I wrote an extention method below which will work with your any object. However, it will only flatten Dictionary<string, string> at the moment. Will try to update it later.

```
public static class ExtentionClasses
{
    public static dynamic Flatten<T>(this T item)
    {
        // Get all the properties not of type dictionary
        var regularProps = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => !typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType));
        var dictionaryProps = item.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType));

        var outputDict = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        // Create a dynamic object
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

        // Add the regular properties
        foreach (var prop in regularProps)
        {
            AddProperty(expando, prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item));
        }

        // Add the dictionary properties
        foreach (var prop in dictionaryProps)
        {
            // convert to dict
            var val = prop.GetValue(item);
            var dict = (Dictionary<string, string>)val;

            foreach(var keyValue in dict)
            {
                AddProperty(expando, keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
            }
        }

        return expando;
    }

    public static void AddProperty(ExpandoObject expando, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        // ExpandoObject supports IDictionary so we can extend it like this
        var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
        if (expandoDict.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            expandoDict[propertyName] = propertyValue;
        else
            expandoDict.Add(propertyName, propertyValue);
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
var person = new Person()
{
    Name = "Jhon",
    DOB = DateTime.Today,
    Address = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"Number", "18"},
        {"Line1", "Knotta Street"},
        {"Line2", "Thrumpton-on-Thames"},
        {"Postcode", "SW1 2AA"}
    }
};

var x = person.Flatten();

Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
Console.WriteLine(x.Postcode);
```

And the results:

```
Jhon
SW1 2AA
```

That way you can still reference the object all you want before printing out the Json Result with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x)`