# Get data from API in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postman

I'm new in API and I have this API retrieve no data:

```
  Dim data As Object = New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
  {"data", "{
  ""Data"": [
      {
   ""CustomerApplicationId"": """",
   ""CustAccount"": """ & AXID & """
      }
      ]
    } "}, {"token", "nMwHCdugwVsyqvHhPYhZHmEEWQWiQCfxVETAV"}, {"company", "companyname"}}
  data = "json= " & data.ToString

  Dim client = New RestClient("http://***/Sales/Sales/***")
  Dim request = New RestRequest()
  request.Method = Method.Post
  request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

  request.AddBody(data)
  responsew = client.Execute(request).Content.ToString
```

I know the token in the body is a little weird but this API like this;
any suggestions to solve the problem?

Comment: If you look at the value of the variable `data` you will see it is `json= System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2[System.Object,System.Object]`. I guess that is not what you intended. What did you want? Is there a reason you can't just use a string instead of going via a Dictionary?

Comment: you are right I want the data retrieved from this API but it's nothing when this function end 
when I send this request in postman I have so much data 
I want to know where is the problem in my code

Comment: This is when I call the function
Dim GetCustPoints = GetPoints("Cust_0042117")
and here where return the data in JSON2 and it's empty 
 Dim json2 As JObject = JObject.Parse(GetCustPoints.Result)
if this helps you to get what I need

Comment: Do the answers to [How do I convert a dictionary to a JSON String in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597349/how-do-i-convert-a-dictionary-to-a-json-string-in-c) help?

Comment: request.AddParameter("data", data("data"), ParameterType.GetOrPost)
 request.AddParameter("token", data("token"), ParameterType.GetOrPost)
 request.AddParameter("company", data("company"), ParameterType.GetOrPost)
I Used this way and It's done 
Thanks for helping me.